# Question about applying chain rule on composition of Complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, chain-rule, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma : [a,b]\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be differentiable functions.

Can i apply the chain rule on the derivative of $f(\gamma (t))$ with respect to $t$?

i.e. $\dfrac{d}{dt} f(\gamma (t)) = f'(\gamma (t)).\gamma'(t)$

Why is this correct, or why is this wrong?

If this is wrong, then should i apply the Cauchy-Riemann equation instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. And quite useful.

On the other hand, no, you cannot apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations instead. Actually, this makes no sense, because the Cauchy-Riemann equations are for complex functions defined on an open subset of $\mathbb C$, whereas the domain of $f\circ\gamma$ is $[a,b]$.

Comment: Why is this correct? I know only of the chain rule for the case of composition of complex functions and the case of composition of real functions. But $\gamma$ maps from real to complex set.

Comment: @LittleRookie And $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb C$.